# Designing app that use node editor approach

Tags: graph

By Node Graph app I mean, something like: Blender's Node Editor, Unity Shader Graph, https://www.draw.io/

I want to develop app to design and simulate logic gate (Something like https://academo.org/demos/logic-gate-simulator/ https://sciencedemos.org.uk/logic_gates.php https://simulator.io/), how do I approach such goal?

What framework should I use, is there an open source example, or some reading material

Comment: What kind of programming language do you want to use, what's your experience in this kind of work? You're not giving us much to work with here.

Comment: @Rik I want to use OOP, maybe Dart, C#, or TypeScript
I have zero experience in this kind of thing, tho I have a lot experience in Flutter

Sorry for not giving enough information, I just getting started at this and don't know how to approach this problem. Reading material would be good

Comment: Are you looking to make a desktop application or will it be web-based? Blender is a desktop application, but it sounds like you want it to be web-based. If you are willing to learn a slightly different programing language, the wxwidgets (written in C++) library is really good. I was able to make a really feature-rich node editor graph usingthe wxPython bindings. Here is a list of bindings for other languages: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_wxWidgets)